# PackageReference Microsoft.AspNetCore.App change of manner from core 2.2 to core 3 & 3.1

Tags: c#, solid-principles, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.1, packagereference

In the past, in my project I create a blank solution and add

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.2.5" />
```

in class library, so I was able to refer this class library project to an others and use what I needed. For example in my solution I had `Core` folder and `Web` folder. My web application started from "asp.net core web application" that was in Web folder and has reference to "Core" folder class libraries like core, data, services and ... .

Now with ASP.NET Core 3 I have problem with this approach, it causes an error; how can I implement this approach?

For example you can see NopCommerce approach in nop 4.2, its similar to mine.
Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution. main problem was in IWebHostEnvironment that it solved by framework reference instead of package reference.

You can add

```
<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
```

in `<ItemGroup> ... </ItemGroup>` and enjoy it.